# How can I return a specific type from a union based type using a generic function using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

My API has a pattern to return a concrete type or a `BadResult` TypeScript type like below:

```
type Result1 = CreatedPersonResult | BadResult;
type Result2 = CreatedRoleResult | BadResult;
```

I want to create a generic wrapper function that I can pass `Result1` or `Result2` to, and I want to return only the success result. E.g. `CreatedPersonResult`.

I believe I could use the `Exclude` TypeScript option.

If it was a `BadResult`, throwing an error is fine.

```
const resolveActualType = (result: T): Exclude<T, BadResult> => {    
    // if(... is BadResult) {
    //   throw Error();
    // }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So what's your question or problem you are facing? You stated what you wanted to do and what you think would work, but what *actually* happened or what *actually* occured?

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is in constraining the generic parameter type so that TypeScript can infer that the remaining `result` (after potentially throwing an error) matches the `Exclude<T, BadResult>` return type, i.e. can no longer be a `BadResult`.

A very simple solution is to take a union directly for the function parameter, and to let TS infer the generic parameter type `T` as the part *without* `BadResult`, instead of the entire union:

```
// T is inferred as the type without BadResult directly
const resolveActualType = <T,>(result: T | BadResult): T => {
    result
    //^? BadResult | T

    if (isBadResult(result)) {
        result
        //^? BadResult
        throw Error();
    }

    return result;
    //     ^? T
}

declare const r1b: Result1
const r1 = resolveActualType(r1b)
//    ^? CreatedPersonResult

declare const r2b: Result2
const r2 = resolveActualType(r2b)
//    ^? CreatedRoleResult
 | BadResult;

// Actual implementation of type guard predicate depends on actual BadResult type
declare function isBadResult(result: unknown): result is BadResult
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgThAhsCATAChOBnA9gOwCUJsBXAG2CgF4oBvKMALin1IFsAjLKAXwChQkWAmRpCuchGJlKNelDgs2XHgKHQAQolQyKVWg07KO3OH36Dw0PZQCM8+EhQYseIiX1QAPlG27PSgBuK2FbYAAmR1EXCSlwnz8dcJD+AHo0qABBAGNgUkRyKABLdjApdgh8YGRigihUCEh8VGwoesQ8gqL-BI1+RpzyRAQoADNSfDy6-BLsXsDgAAoEWWAWSYBrfFwAd3wAShZVr2K2hbXLDKgAFTmS-DGsBFQoRDbgAAtoDShd4q+uFIVAuXlQxQQeXIIH4OQI2Coq0kADcILl8oUbtZ5AAeG4AGgAfCtFiw7r5QZQjrcaIT6PwoIzFIsGUyMgA9AD8liZJTGUCWZ0pyxOVIO9N5vNFwFZkqgHO5csZXzgeygAFE4Kq4EsDiFeQJZcz8nBZtL9WzMryufxDYNhqM4fgEYo7MYoOE7LD4YiHLQkeRUejuljICs3Qd0lbGTaBhAhiNoE6XXAIu7whFvc7EVF-SQUWiupjrCs05HrkybUA)